# Connecting to computers within a OpenVPN network with SSH

Tags: ssh, openvpn

I have OpenVPN installed on a VPS and I wish to connect to any computers connected to it via SSH by using the subnet IP provided by OpenVPN. For some reason, whenever I try to start a SSH connection (say from 10.8.0.2 to 10.8.0.3), it doesn't work. Not because the connection is denied but because it hangs as if it was unable to find the target. Of course, I am already assuming that all the computers already have an OpenSSH server configured.

Some details:

- Script I used to configure OpenVPN on my VPS: https://gist.github.com/dmytro/0606cb32e42fc0918466
- I am using identical `.ovpn` files across all computers. The file already has the certificates and keys embedded on it.
- The option `duplicate-cn` is enabled on OpenVPN's config file.
- Even though I can ping to any target computer, `nmap` says that the host is down.

Comment: If you can ping any target computer then routing and forwarding are working. Check you firewalls.

Comment: Please show your full OpenVPN config file in the question.